# Is it okay to book a plane ticket before the date of invitation? (C/VV visa) to Romania

Tags: visas, applications, romania, invitation-letters, egyptian-citizens

I have an invitation from the host, approved by the immigration border in Romania, and on the paper it says that the invitation takes place starting from August 1.

The visa application to the embassy requires me to book the plane tickets to submit my application.

Is it fine to book the ticket before the invitation date by like a week?

Or does the visa have to strictly start from the date of invitation?

I am from Egypt.

Thank you.

Comment: It would probably be more typical to coincide the flight booking with the invitation date, but it would depend on circumstances eg why do you plan to arrive early, where will you stay until you move to your host, who will cover [subsistence](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/system/files/2022-07/handbook-annex_25_en_0.pdf) expenses etc etc and how you intend to document all that for application purposes.

Comment: I would arrive early because the ticket would be much cheaper, and I would still stay at the host's home when I arrive, I guess that would be illegal?

Comment: I don’t know if it would be illegal but since even having an approved invitation doesn’t guarantee you’ll be given a visa, putting in an application that doesn’t match it might well harm your chances of success.

Comment: That is a good point, I guess might have to play it safe.